# Tensorflow memory leak while using GPU but in CPU is OK

Tags: memory, tensorflow, memory-leaks, gpu

While using GPU to train my model, the memory of CPU would exhaust after a few epochs. However, if I use CPU instead, this behaviour wouldn't occur.

I tried a couple of different combinations, but none of them worked:

- cuda8.0.44 cudnn5.1 tensorflow1.2.1
- cuda8.0.44 cudnn6.0 tensorflow1.2.1
- cuda8.0.44 cudnn6.0 tensorflow1.3.0
- cuda8.0.61(with patch) cudnn6.0 tensorflow1.3.0

I'm using ubuntu14.0.4 with python2.7

Based on the suggestion in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861956/gpu-poolallocator-explodes-the-cpu-memory), I already tried the following:

1. Calling `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()`
2. Use `tcmalloc` instead of `malloc`
3. Recompiled tensorflow with different hardcoded params

Comment: maybe try setting TF_CUDA_HOST_MEM_LIMIT_IN_MB to some small value?

Comment: the next step might be to get memory profile to see who's actually taking up the memory, like in here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3009#issuecomment-228867287

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov os.environ["TF_CUDA_HOST_MEM_LIMIT_IN_MB"]="10000" is added in my code but it seems like no work,  the memory would still increase to 32G and stuck

Comment: I wonder if it's connected to this issue -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445109/why-is-my-c-program-suddenly-using-30g-of-virtual-memory

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I also using pprof to check where the leak happend. It shows that the nodes "cudbgApiDetach"   and  "cuVDPAUCtxCreate" are the problem, "tensorflow BFCAllocator Extend"  is stable. But I have no idea how to fix the leak

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I using htop to check, the VIRT is stable in 55.0G but RES still increase

Comment: It sounds like cuda driver issue, maybe you could drive a different version of cuda

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov replace the cuda  with 7.0 and 7.5 still leak. It drive me crazy about 3weeks..lol

Comment: oh....those are old! Google continuous builds all test TF with CUDA 8.0 and there's an option to use TF with CUDA 9.0